# how to use rigidbody constraints in unity 2d

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner I stated unity about 9 months now I made several 3d games I am making a 2d game and I am trying to freeze all positions of my players in an if statement how to do that in a 2d game

Comment: Please add your attempt.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a Rigidbody2D (in a variable called myRigidbody), you can use:

```
myRigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;
```

And if you just want to freeze your position and not your rotation, you can use:

```
myRigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePosition;
```

Hope this helped :)